# can transport stream file (.ts) be just audio files?

Tags: transport-stream

I want to build up a live audio broadcast app, using HLS to stream the audio, can transport stream file (.ts) be just audio files? if yes, how can I get a list of .ts audio file from a ffmpeg command?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, **Nope**: `.ts` files (Transport Stream) are ''containers'' for multimedia data (audio, video, subtitles, etc...). It also carries a lot of metadata information that allows a host (Set-top-box or TV) to tune on a channel and play a program.

So `.ts` files describe "programs"... However you can have programs that contains only audio data (like radio channels), so you can still have hope ;)

[`ffmpeg`](http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/ffmpeg-%E2%80%93-the-swiss-army-knife-of-internet-streaming-%E2%80%93-part-iv/) should probably do that, but it seems [VLC](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=75915) also can.

Comment: Do we need to use MPEG-2 Transport Stream for audio-only streaming to a HTTP Live Stream server?